# Job for httpd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status httpd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details

Tags: apache, centos, centos7, httpd.conf

I have installed a fresh copy of Centos 7. Then I restarted Apache but the Apache failed to start. I have 3 days stucked in this issue. Even the support can not figure out the error.

```
sudo service httpd start


Failed to start apache :
Job for httpd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status httpd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.


httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2016-05-09 16:08:02 BST; 59s ago
     Docs: man:httpd(8)
           man:apachectl(8)
 Main PID: 5710 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

May 09 16:08:02 mike079.startdedicated.de systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
May 09 16:08:02 mike079.startdedicated.de httpd[5710]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 85.25.12.20:80
May 09 16:08:02 startdedicated.de httpd[5710]: no listening sockets available, shutting down
May 09 16:08:02 startdedicated.de httpd[5710]: AH00015: Unable to open logs
May 09 16:08:02 startdedicated.de systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 09 16:08:02.startdedicated.de kill[5712]: kill: cannot find process ""
May 09 16:08:02 .startdedicated.de systemd[1]: httpd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
May 09 16:08:02startdedicated.de systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
May 09 16:08:02 startdedicated.de systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
May 09 16:08:02 mike: httpd.service failed.
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From your output:

> no listening sockets available, shutting down

what basically means, that any port in which one apache is going to be listening is already being used by another application.

`netstat -punta | grep LISTEN`

Will give you a list of all the ports being used and the information needed to recognize which process is so you can `kill` `stop` or do whatever you want to do with it.

After doing a `nmap` of your ip I can see that

```
80/tcp    open     http
```

so I guess you sorted it out.

Comment: Thanks I solved the isse there was missmatch with ports.

Comment: I am kind of lost after the line `After doing a nmap of your ip ..`. Could you tell me how should I test after that?

Comment: @John `nmap ip` is the fastest way to go

Answer (score 30):

I got the same error because of a simple typo in vhost.conf.
Remember to make sure you don't have any errors in the config files.

```
apachectl configtest
```

Comment: suggest using "sudo" in front if getting PEM file type errors which may require the elevated prompt to see the files.

Comment: If you run httpd in another user account, instead of simply adding `sudo` you might want to use `sudo -u [httpd user]` to check file privilege.

Answer (score 10):

In my case I got the error simply because I had changed the Listen 80 to listen 443 in the file

```
/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

Since I had installed `mod_ssl` using the yum commands

```
yum -y install mod_ssl
```

there was a duplicate listen 443 directive in the file `ssl.conf` created during `mod_ssl` installation.

You can verify this if you have duplicate listen 80 or 443 by running the below command in linux centos (My linux)

```
grep  '443' /etc/httpd/conf.d/*
```

below is sample output

```
/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:Listen 443 https
/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:<VirtualHost _default_:443>
/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:#ServerName www.example.com:443
```

Simply reverting the listen 443 in httd.conf to listen 80 fixed my issue.

Comment: `grep  '443' /etc/httpd/conf.d/*` saved my live. turns out there are ssl.conf and i set vrtual host on the httpd.conf

Comment: Saved the day. Is there any way to see the proper error message?  `apachectl configtest` only validates the syntax.

Answer (score 7):

on command line type `journalctl -xe` and the results will be

```
SELinux is preventing /usr/sbin/httpd from name_bind access on the tcp_socket port 83 or 80
```

This means that the SELinux is running on your machine and you need to disable it. then edit the configuration file by type the following

```
nano /etc/selinux/config
```

Then find the line `SELINUX=enforce` and change to `SELINUX=disabled`

Then type the following and run the command to start httpd

`setenforce 0`

Lastly start a server

```
systemctl start httpd
```

Answer (score 4):

**Allow Apache Through the Firewall**

Allow the default HTTP and HTTPS port, ports 80 and 443, through firewalld:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=80/tcp
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=443/tcp
```

And reload the firewall:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```

Answer (score 2):

Some other service may be using port 80: try to stop the other services: HTTPD, SSL, NGINX, PHP, with the command **sudo systemctl stop**  and then use the command **sudo systemctl start httpd**

Comment: sudo systemctl stop HTTPD, sudo systemctl stop SSL, sudo systemctl stop NGINX sudo systemctl stop PHP

Answer (score 1):

For me the issue was the following:

```
[Sat Sep 10 00:43:20.999998 2022] [auth_digest:error] [pid 123456] (2)No such file or directory: AH01762: Failed to create shared memory segment on file /run/httpd/authdigest_shm.128124
[Sat Sep 10 00:43:20.999999 2022] [auth_digest:error] [pid 123456] (2)No such file or directory: AH01760: failed to initialize shm - all nonce-count checking and one-time noncesdisabled
```

*I have just tailed the error logs to get those two line above:*

```
*ADMINSHELL* :/var/opt/custom_path/logs/httpd # tail error_log
```

So the problem was that this folder was missing: /run/httpd/

Solution:

```
mkdir /run/httpd
chown root:httpd /run/httpd
chmod 0710 /run/httpd
```

After this is done. You will be able to restart the service:

```
systemctl restart httpd.service
```

Double check:

```
systemctl status httpd.service
```

Answer (score 0):

The error could be anywhere, configs, libraries or the binaries. Error in the control process is a general error thrown by the system when its not able to start/restart the service. In my case one of libraries linked to the exe in the .service file has a problem. Fixing that library solved the problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

try this cmd to know the missing config or error in the file configuration
$ apachectl configtest

Answer (score 0):

I had almost the same error, and I found the error on `vhost.conf` file, which is located on `/etc/httpd/conf.d/vhost.conf`.

If you were configuring the virtual host, I suggest you look at the following file and find if you have any errors there.

`/etc/httpd/conf.d/vhost.conf`

Answer (score 0):

For me also the same error happens after adding [dummy SSL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/SSL-on-amazon-linux-2.html?fbclid=IwAR0t9X9WH6b6Kvbg8iF_54OEWKr_Y1dJbvXw5eKHl7TJoif82TKy73STe78)

in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf` file it's created a line like,

```
SLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/localhost.crt
```

I changed it from **SLCertificateFile** to **SSLCertificateFile**

```
SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/localhost.crt
```

And after apache restart it started working fine.

Answer (score -2):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.YOURDOMAIN.COM
    ServerAlias YOURDOMAIN.COM
    DocumentRoot /var/www/YOURDOMAIN.COM/public_html
    ErrorLog /var/www/YOURDOMAIN.COM/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/YOURDOMAIN.COM/requests.log combined

    DocumentRoot /var/www/YOURDOMAIN.COM/public_html
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/YOURDOMAIN.COM/public_html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Please explain more about your solution. Your answer is not helpful for anyone.